# How to open every link of an html page in a new tab?

Tags: html

Currently i have webpages which contains research reference links (250 links/page(3 pages)).
And all the links open in the same tab.

I have given below code to some of the references

```
<a href="http://www.websitename.com" target="_blank">
```

Is there any more elegant way to make them open in new tab than editing each and every link and add target ?

**Edit 1 :**

Webpages have been already designed in such a way that it will open in same window.I need to change them to new tab.

Also website links are not same.they differ .

Thanks

Comment: If the HTML document is static HTML, just use find/replace in your editor

Comment: open in another tab using target="_blank"

Comment: If you are hand coding 250 anchor tags then manually is the way to go, or find/replace. If you have code which produces this HTML then adding some code to your loop is easy.

Comment: :( ohh but the code is already done..we are just manipulating so as to open them in new tab !

Comment: If you are okay to use javascript, you can do this automatically. Do you need the javascript solution?

Comment: @HiteshValaAhir yes code open ups in new tab..but my question is an alternative for manual ones..also please see the edit1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no elegant way of doing this in HTML.

You'll have to go through each one manually, or do a find & replace.

If you're using some sort of server-side technology then you could put each anchor in a wrapper.

Alternatively if you're ok to use some client side javascript, you could update each anchor on the fly. For example using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adtdayjx/

Comment: thank you @Curt for your response..could you show example edited in answer

Comment: @utility Updated answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jQuery?

```
$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a default target for all hyperlinks and forms on a page:

```
<head>
<base target="_blank">
</head>
```

Comment: You beat me to it! See also: [the MDN page about `<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, you can execute this function when the page loads,

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```